# Уроки для создания игр

Tags: java, разработка-игр, книги

Подскажите java уроки для создания  игр. Самое главное и простое знаю.

Comment: Чувствую, что вы еще сильно разочаруетесь в `gamedev'е` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написание игр на Java может быть не оправдано с точки зрения производительности.

Но если вы хотите именно Java(и хорошо знаете сам язык), можете для начала посмотреть эти туториалы: [Java Game Development Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECA331A6709F40B79D&feature=plcp).

В уроках человек рассказывает простой способ написание игр на Java с использованием движка Slick (который, например, использует легендарный Minecraft).